# Can I disable the Text Extractor shortcut from PowerToys in favor of ShareX's OCR?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm having a problem where I cannot use the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut in ShareX. I'd love to be able to use this shortcut so that the next time I set up an operating system I have it in my muscle memory that this is the Text Extractor for Microsoft's PowerToys (I understand that the software is not always readily available).

I've turned on this policy setting in the Local Group Policy Editor, but it disables every single Windows key shortcut that is reserved by the operating system and I use some of them, like <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you have PowerToys installed or not? Microsoft doesn't "reserve" a key command for software not installed. You can configure shortcut keys in ShareX I believe, though it's been a year since I ran that software regularly. What setting did you turn on in LGPO? Please start at the beginning, clearly describe how your system is currently configured relevant to this question, tell us what you're trying to do, and tell us what you have tried and the research that you have done. Use the EDIT button to fix your question.

Comment: They do reserve the key command, because even without it installed it will be reserved for the operating system.

Comment: Then it is reserved to something else in the OS, or you had the software installed before and did not disable the key command before uninstalling and it did not remove that. The OS itself does not reserve key commands for software that is not included in the OS. Your question still lacks the info we have requested that you add to it. Please take the time to Edit your question to make it better. This is in your best interest, as good questions are more likely to get more attention and good answers.